# Why does Lombok's @Nonnull have CLASS retention?

Tags: java, lombok

What is the benefit for `@NonNull` to have `CLASS` retention level over `SOURCE`?

I've found this old discussion - https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/895

But it doesn't seem to answer my question.

The coolest thing about Lombok is that it enhances Java language with virtually zero cost to runtime. If I develop, say, a library, I want it to have as few compile/runtime dependencies as possible. And for most part Lombok is great in that regard.

But then there is the `@NonNull` annotation. Even through the absence of Lombok's jar in the classpath doesn't lead to any critical errors - like in the case of the Github issue linked above - it can still affect the execution. Some annotation processing tools might give a verbose warning (some might even fail, who knows). At the very least there is an overhead of `@NonNull` annotation being present in the bytecode.

All of the other Lombok annotations seem to have `SOURCE` retention level. Why does `@NonNull` need to bring such an inconsistency?

Comment: I don't see how your point about runtime cost is relevant. It's just `RetentionPolicy.CLASS`, not `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`. Presumably, the annotation is stored in the class file for documentation purposes. Other users of your compiled class, who may have no access to the source code, can see clearly what should not be null.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think with classes being loaded dynamically my point is still very relevant. I agree that it makes sense to have Nonnull with CLASS retention for your public API. And there plenty of other Nonnull annotations out there to serve that purpose. I always thought that Lombok is not about that.

Comment: Not too familiar with annotation processing nor javac but guess it has something to do with other Lombok annotations like `@Setter` and `@Builder`. Maybe those need a pre-compiled class file where `@NonNull` retains or so. Hopping also that some of the authors clarify this.